# View model with the authorization example

Tags: resolvejs

I want to restrict access to view models according to the authorization or JWT. I found examples for the read models, but how to implement it for the view models in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

In `resolve` framework every view-model can have own [serializer](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/master/examples/hello-world/common/view-models/view-model-name.serialize_state.js) and [deserializer](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/master/examples/hello-world/common/view-models/view-model-name.deserialize_state.js). These functions are used for view-models which have non-trivial state object, which cannot be automatically serialized by `JSON.stringify` and be restored within `JSON.parse` - for example, it's useful for [Immutable.JS](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) or [seamless-immutable](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable).

In fact [serializer](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/master/examples/hello-world/common/view-models/view-model-name.serialize_state.js) has two arguments - first is state object for serialization, and second argument is JWT token from invoker. Since view-model is always had been invoked from current client, either HTTP request or [API handler](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/master/docs/api-handlers.md), JWT token is always present and can be used for access restriction

```
const serializeState = (state, jwtToken) => {
    if(jwtToken != null && !isGoodToken(jwtToken)) { // JWT token is present and custom validation failed
        throw new Error('Access denied') 
    }
    return JSON.stringify(state) // Or custom serialize procedure
}
export default serializeState
```

Important notice: do not restrict serialized state access in case of `jwtToken` absence, since it used for internal purposes in snapshot adapters. Always allow return serialized state if second argument is undefined. Else if jwtToken present and invalid, error can be thrown to restrict access.